# MOC (Music on Console) Raspberry Pi Volume Control Not Working

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I tried mocp -v command on my Ubuntu PC and it works perfectly fine. But it just won't work on my rasberry pi!

Controlling the volume on the RPi using alsa mixer (amixer) works but it produces bad sound quality becuase of the way it adjusts the volume.

Can someone help me figure this out ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> ```
>   up+5
> ```
>
> <       down-5

or

right alt + >
right alt + <